# Lua non-integer randomise

Tags: random, lua, random-seed

I'm new at LUA and I need a help with code in using function `math.random(...)`. The problem is if I need to generate integer values I just use

```
math.random(-1, 1) -- This is gonna be -1, 0 or 1. Profit.
```

But if I need non-integers between -1 and 0?

```
math.random(-1.0, 1.0) -- Still -1, 0 or 1. No profit.
```

I tried using this: `-1.01, 1.01` but it is not gonna generate a number between values exactly I need.

How do I generate non-integer value between 1 and 0?

Comment: I think there's an error in your question, math.random() generates random values between 0 and 1.

Comment: @poorandunlucky yes I think I just forgot it, but I meant that I need to generate non-integer values for example between x and y variables, not just 1 and 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without arguments, `math.random` returns a floating-point number between 0 and 1. You can get other ranges by multiplying and adding:

```
math.random() * 2 - 1
```

Or more generally:

```
math.random() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! Is there a way I could limit fractions from the value I get with `math.random() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum`? For example if I use `math.random(-1.1, 1.1)` I'm getting only tenth from the value (`x point y`) or if I use `math.random(-1.11, 1.11)` I'm going to get the hundred from the value (`x point yz`). But using this I'm getting a very big fraction.

Comment: Do you just need to round off the output, or do you really need a number that's right at a hundredth? Either way, that sounds like it should be a separate question.

Comment: I guess you're right. Im just curious because the original way worked like this so it would be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like math.random(-1, 1) + ( math.random(1, 99) / 100 ). Hopefully this helps a bit. math.random will only get whole numbers and integers. It won't return floats unfortunately.